# angular add new observable operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, observable

Based on the information from this site [How To Debug RxJs - A Simple Way For Debugging Rxjs Observables](http://blog.angular-university.io/debug-rxjs/) I made a new file called `observable-debug-operator.ts` that I import in my app component with `import './observable-debug-operator';`

The contents of the observable-debug-operator file are below

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// add debugging to Observables
Observable.prototype.debug = function (message: string) {
  return this.do(
    function (next) {
      if (environment.observableDebugging) {
        console.log(message, next);
      }
    },
    function (err) {
      if (environment.observableDebugging) {
        console.error('ERROR >>> ', message , err);
      }
    },
    function () {
      if (environment.observableDebugging) {
        console.log('Completed.', message);
      }
    }
  );
};
declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    debug: (...any) => Observable<T>;
  }
}
```

This is working as expected and I can subscribe to an observable and debug it to the console with

```
this.service.methodThatReturnsObservable()
  .debug('doing something with an observable')
  .subscribe(...do something...);
```

however when I run my karma tests I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

or

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

I tried including `import 'the/path/to/observable-debug-operator';` in my test spec but I still get the error. Does anyone know why the debug operator is not being found in the test but works fine in the actual code?

Comment: The error doesn't say that your debug operator is undefined, its more about that `Observable.prototype` or `this.service.methodThatReturnsObservable` is undefined.

Comment: @cyrix absolutely correct. I don't know why I misread that error. I had mocked the service so I needed to return an observable from the mocked method. Now it works fine. If you make it an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error doesn't mean your `debug` is undefined. It says that either your service methode or Observable.prototype is `undefined`. So check if each of them is available.